# Converting ISO-8601 string to local date in typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs, primeng-calendar

I am developing in Angular 6. I keep form values as json in a database when new record is saved.If end user wants to show exists record , I fill form components from json data.But I got into trouble for casting date values . I wasn't be able to cast correctly my local date.
I have tried with moment,but didn't work:

```
console.log("string Value",stringValue);
let date = moment(stringValue,"yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ");                             
console.log("date",date.format('DD/MM/YYY HH:mm:ss'));
```

> string Value  output: 2019-01-17T21:00:00.000Z
>
> console output actual : date 18/01/2019 01:00:00
>
> but console output expected : date 18/01/2019 00:00:00

I tried *"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.fffZ"* but didn't work too.

EXTRA INFORMATION

saving data:

```
process.data = JSON.stringify(this.form.getRawValue());
save(process);
```

html(primeng):

```
<p-calendar formControlName="startDate" dateFormat="dd.mm.yy"></p-calendar>
```

Comment: Which time zone are you in?

Comment: @str GMT+03:00 Istanbul

Comment: Did you check the time zone settings of your computer? Maybe it is caused by a wrong DST configuration. What browser / OS version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parse your `'2019-01-17T21:00:00.000Z'` input using [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) since it represents time in UTC

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

and then convert it to local timezone using [`local()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/).

Here a live sample:

```js
const stringValue = '2019-01-17T21:00:00.000Z';
let date = moment.utc(stringValue).local();
console.log("date", date.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Weird. If the input string ends with "Z", moment should understand that it is UTC without the explicit `.utc()`.

Comment: @VincenzoC I tried it but I set to form control wrongly, thanks

Comment: @Touffy `Z` stands for `+00:00`, I think that it is fine that moment _implicitly_ understand that input is UTC. `moment('2019-01-17T21:00:00.000Z')` would give the same output of the code in my answer, but I think that using `moment.utc()` and `local()` is clearer. Probably the biggest issue in the OP code was `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ` tokens.

Comment: If anyone is still looking at this answer, moment.js is deprecated.  You shouldn't be using this library anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The moment-timezone library was built to "parse and display dates in any timezone".

To construct a date-time object in a specific timezone, use:

```
let now = moment.tz('Europe/Istanbul');
```

To view the UTC value, use

```
now.toISOString()
```

To view the local timezone value, use:

```
now.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS');
```